# Entity Framework 1-To-* and 1-to-1

Tags: c#, entity-framework

(Entity Framework 6, .NET 4, VS 2010)

I have created a small Blog project to illustrate the problem. This is a Blog that has many posts but only one of the posts act as the main post.

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> PostEntities { get; set; }

    public int? MainPostId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MainPostId")]
    public virtual Post MainPostEntity { get; set; }  // Problem here
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
    public virtual Blog BlogEntity { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .HasOptional(b => b.MainPostEntity)
    .WithRequired(p => p.BlogEntity);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<EFTestContext>(null);
    EFTestContext db = new EFTestContext();
    Post[] posts = db.Posts.ToArray(); // Error here
}
```

If I remove the navigation property `public virtual Post MainPostEntity` everything works as expected. However, when I add it, I get:

`base {System.SystemException} = {"The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'MainPostEntity' on type 'EFTest.Blog' is not valid. The foreign key name 'MainPostId' was not found on the dependent type 'EFTest.Post'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names."}`

If I remove the fluent API call, I get `{"Invalid column name 'Blog_Id'."}`

If I change the attribute from `[ForeignKey("MainPostId")]` to `[ForeignKey("Id")]` I get the following error `{"Invalid column name 'Blog_Id'."}`

> What am I doing wrong? 
>   How do I enable the navigation property from Blog to the Main Post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you're creating two relationships between the same two tables and EF can't distinguish which relationship the navigation property `BlogEntity` is part of. Using the fluent api you can explicitly tell it so, the data annotations are then not needed.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(b => b.PostEntities).
                            WithRequired(p => p.BlogEntity).
                            HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId).
                            WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasOptional(b => b.MainPostEntity).
                            WithMany().
                            HasForeignKey(b => b.MainPostId).
                            WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```